# What should I use in place of getWidth() and getHeight() to know when width is greater and when height is greater

Tags: android, fragment, display, window-managers, fragmentmanager

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();


        WindowManager wm= getWindowManager();
        Display d=wm.getDefaultDisplay();

        if (d.getWidth()>d.getHeight())
        {
            Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
        }
        else
        {
            Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f2);
        }
    ft.commit();
    }
}
```

I am trying to use fragments in android and want to display `fragment1` when width of display is greater than height of display and `fragment2` when height of display is greater than  width of display but when using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` android studio is saying that these methods are depricated. 
Then how to know when width is greater and when height is greater?

Comment: are you trying to show fragment one on portrait and fragment 2 on landscape

Comment: @Shararti KAKA yes....I am trying to do the same thing

Comment: use `DisplayMetrics `

Comment: When you get four answers in as many minutes, it's a sure sign that you did not do enough research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DisplayMetrics` instead of `Display`.

**Try this:**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft= fm.beginTransaction();

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        if (width > height)
        {
            Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
        }
        else
        {
            Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f2);
        }

        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ankit kindly read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: sir, I was about to check the tick but the site was giving warning that I can check the tick only after 10 minutes so I was waing for that

Comment: You have already accepted this answer. Thank you :) Make sure to give an up-vote later.

Comment: already done friend

Comment: Previously you accepted my answer but now you have changed it. May I know why?

Answer (score 3):

You can use **DisplayMetrics**

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int Width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

if (Width  > height )
    {
        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
    }
    else
    {
        Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f2);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the valuable time

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
mContext.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get width and height.

```
int Measuredwidth = 0;  
int Measuredheight = 0;  
Point size = new Point();
WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)    {
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    Measuredwidth = size.x;
    Measuredheight = size.y; 
}else{
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
    Measuredwidth = d.getWidth(); 
    Measuredheight = d.getHeight(); 
}
```

Comment: where is this x and y coming from

Comment: it is the display x and y dimensions in pixels

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
 if(dm.widthPixels > dm.heightPixels) {
     //width is greater, i.e. landscape
     Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
 } else {
     //height is greater i.e. portrait
     Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
     ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f2);
 }
```

You can detect orientation directly by overriding `onConfigurationChanges` in `MainActivity`

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f1);
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, f2);
    }
}

//Add configChanges in manifest
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```